# How to safely remove HP bloatware in Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, bloatware

I have Windows 10 Home in HP laptop which contains:-
1. HPCeement
2. HPJumpStartLaunch
3. HPRegistrationService
4. HPSupportAssistant
5. HPSureConnect
What are the uses of this softwares?
Is it safe to remove them?
How wll it affect my laptop if i remove?
Is it safe if I use Malwarebytes AdwCleaner 8.0.1 to remove them?
Or there is another software or manual way to remove them?

Comment: IMO you don't need any of these applications. The First thing I always do if I buy a new laptop, is to completely format the drive and reinstall Windows from scratch

Comment: Did you google any of these programs? This is safe to use, you can choose what to remove after it builds a list of crap it finds>>>>https://www.pcdecrapifier.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. CEEment - I'd remove this one!

> CEEment stands for Customer Experience Enhancement. CEEment
>   (HPCEE.exe) is the reporting tool that HP uses to collect and study
>   anonymous data. You can activate CEEment when you set up your
>   computer. Or, you can activate using HP Advisor or HP Support
>   Assistant at any time. Some of the data reported using CEEment
>   includes your model number, OS, region, locale, and BIOS version. If
>   you wish to know specifically which data was collected, launch HP
>   Support Assistant. Click Settings, scroll down to the bottom of the
>   Health Analysis tab, and then click View information collected by HP.

2. Jumpstart - You don't need this if you're going to remove McAfee and you're going to personalize the computer yourself.

> HP JumpStart guides you through a multi-step welcome process that
>   includes HP Registration, McAfee registration, HP Dropbox offer
>   activation, and an HP JumpStart Concierge screen with tips to help you
>   personalize your computer and install apps.

3. HP Registration Service - Does what it says on the tin. You can use it to register your device with HP. If this doesn't provide additional support or warranty options, I'd remove/ignore.
4. Support Assistant - Useful for BIOS updates and driver updates, although you can do these manually.

> HP Support Assistant helps keep your HP computer in working order by
>   finding updates and providing troubleshooting tools. Most HP computers
>   come with HP Support Assistant. Click the app icon in the task bar, or
>   search Windows for 'support assistant' to open the tool.

5. HP Sure Connect - Looks to be a tool for fixing broken drivers...

> HP Sure Connect (HP Wireless Rescue Tool) for supported models running
>   a supported operating system. HP Sure Connect automatically recovers
>   the driver of a communications device that has stopped functioning.

If AdwCleaner wants to remove them and is able to, then sure go ahead.